# (Design) In pandas, why is melting a function but pivoting a method?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, melt

Let's say I have some data, `df`, and I've imported pandas and converted the data into a pandas Data Frame format:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Now if I want to melt this Data Frame, then I have to use the `pd.melt` function -- in particular, this functionality is not associated to any particular Data Frame `df` in question.

But if I want to pivot this Data Frame, then I can (have to?) use a method associated with `df` specifically, `df.pivot(...)` or `df.pivot_table(...)`. (Yes, every instance of a `pandas.DataFrame` object has the same method, I just mean that the syntax is different.)

> **Question:** Does anyone know of any interviews with or papers/blog posts/etc. written by Wes McKinney where he explains the philosophy/logic behind this design decision?

My guess is that the intention is to draw attention to different structural aspects of the two operations, but I am not sure which is the major difference that Wes McKinney had in mind.

Comment: `melt` is now a first class method. So, your question really has no answer except for, in your version of pandas, they hadn't got around to implementing it yet.

Comment: Actually, as of Pandas version 20.0.0 melt is a dataframe method. [see docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.3/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas-dataframe-melt)

Comment: Update you pandas then you can do `df.melt`

Comment: I think that the fact that pandas 20.0.0 happens to have `df.melt` is besides the point. Perhaps if the OP had not given specific examples then people would be more likely to answer the actual question asked, which is "Why were some operations in pandas implemented as DataFrame methods while others were implemented as functions that accept a DataFrame?" I think there is an interesting history lesson there if someone happens to know the answer.

Comment: This is mea culpa -- the course on pandas I was taking wasn't using the most up-to-date version of pandas obviously. I apologize for the confusion I caused.

Comment: I'm glad this question was asked because I had exactly the same one (probably doing the same course as @Chill2Macht...).  I agree that if someone knows the answer it would be a very useful history lesson; there are surely some insights into why some things are functions and some methods in general.